# adding duplicated in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have this little code that write a 2 sys argv into a txt file.

First, everything for fine for writing in the file like I want but, the problem is I want to add the number of item if the user enter it and it is already in the list.

Example of input

```
up.py 1.txt apple 23
```

Example of the txt file

```
apple : 20
orange : 28
```

expected output

```
apple : 43
orange : 28
```

The thing I tried is to make the file as a dictionary and then add the value chiffre in my code I don't understand why it doesn't work the way I entered it.

```
def maj(texte, item, nombre):
    with open(texte, "a") as ouvrir:
        mots_dict = {}
        lecture = ouvrir.readlines()
        for line in lecture:
            line = line.strip("\n")
            mot, chiffre = line.split(" : ")[0].strip(" "), int(line.split(" : ")[1].strip(" "))
            if mot == item:
                sum(mots_dict.values(chiffre))
                ouvrir.write("%s : %s" "\n" % (item, nombre))
                ouvrir.close()
                message = sys.exit()
                return message
            else:
                ouvrir.write("%s : %s" "\n" % (item, nombre))
                ouvrir.close()
                message = sys.exit()
                return message


def main():
    entree = sys.argv[1]
    item = sys.argv[2]
    nombre = sys.argv[3]
    choix = str(entree)
    texte = choix.strip("[']")
    maj(texte, item, nombre)
```

Comment: Save your data as a JSON, not as some text-based format you've cooked-up yourself. Then you will be able to easily serialize and deserialize your data-structures and this all becomes trivial.

Comment: im sorry but i need the dta to be into a txt file in the end. I can add my data very easely if i just keep the ouvrir.write and the rest. 'with open(texte, "a") as ouvrir:                 ouvrir.write("%s : %s" "\n" % (item, nombre))
                ouvrir.close()
                message = sys.exit()
                return message
'

Comment: A JSON file *is* a text file, but what do you mean exactly? If it is important for some reason to have the `.txt` extension, then you can just save it with that extension...

Comment: Also, what is `choix` and why are you stripping brackets from it? If it comes from `sys.argv` then the call to `str` is unecessary...

Comment: are the modification complicated to switch this to json then?..... i know this line seems useless but it works actualy and my question is not about that.

Comment: No, it isn't complicated at all. It is *easier*. That is why JSON exists, for easy text-based serialization that is human readable.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.   You have not shown what the code *does*, and the code you posted has much extra work in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you initialize `mots_dict` to a blank dictionary, but you don't ever add anything to it.

So when you do `sum(mots_dict.values())`, it would return a 0.

If you do not want to change to JSON, and if you are not using the dictionary anywhere else later on, you can leave that part out and just do it like this here:

```
def maj(texte, item, nombre):
        with open(texte, "r") as f_in:
            lecture = f_in.readlines()
        with open(texte, "w") as ouvrir:
            for line in lecture:
               line = line.strip("\n")
               mot, chiffre = line.split(" : ")[0].strip(" "), int(line.split(" : ")[1].strip(" "))
                if mot == item:
                    ouvrir.write("%s : %s" "\n" % (item, str(chiffre + int(nombre))))
                else:
                    ouvrir.write("%s : %s" "\n" % (mot, chiffre))
```

Another thing I noticed is that when you write to `ouvrir`, you just write what value of `nombre` and `item` you got from the user input. If I understand your question, you want to keep the number unchanged from the input file if the item does not match what the user entered. Then you will want to write `mot` and `chiffre` to file, in the `else` block. Moreover, if you call `system.exit()` or `return` within the `if` block, it will not go through all the items in the original file.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer i will test this out, im happy you went in line with that im trying thatll help me to understand better

Comment: Which line are you getting this error in? This is likely a problem with the way you're reading/writing to the file.

Comment: i was able to make it to write into a file but it never worked well. its not adding any new line when entering something that isnt in the file. Also its not replacing any item already writen.

Comment: Try my updated solution. One of the reasons it wasn't replacing is because you were using `with open(texte, "a") as ouvrir:` and `"a"` means opening the file in append mode, that adds whatever you write at the end of the file no matter what it encounters before it.

Comment: did you just update it because its showing edited 5 hours ago and i have tried it and it didnt work

Comment: hi ive used your solution and made some modification to it so it works perfectly now thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import json

def add_from_raw(dict1,key,value):
    dict1['key']=dict1.get(key,0)+value
    json.dumps(dict1,open('file1.json','w'))

if __name__=="__main__"
    filename=sys.argv[1]
    key=sys.argv[2]
    value = sys.argv[3]
    dict1=json.load(open(filename))
    add_from_raw(dict1,key,value)
```

JSON is a better to format to store and query data from.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer i will test this out

Comment: hi i am getting this error with this code    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: You need to create a json file first for the above code to work , just fire up a json as follows vi filename.json and add the following to it 
{"apple":20,"orange":28} 
Post adding the line , :wq the file to save it and try the above code

Answer (score 0):

The main failure is because your program has no code that adds anything together.  The closest is the **sum** statement, which you apply to a list of strings -- giving it **chiffre** (another string) as an argument.  **sum** works on a sequence of numbers.

You need to convert both the input value, and the *one* identified value in the dictionary, to integers.  Then add those with "+", and *then* you can write the result.

Answer (score 0):

Your `maj` method was a little but awkward, so I rewrote it in a cleaner fashion.  This achieves the desired output, while keeping your `main` method the same.

```
import sys

def maj(filename, input_name, input_num):
   with open(filename, 'r') as f:
      for line in f:
         as_list = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), line.split(':')))
         name = as_list[0]
         num = int(as_list[1])
         if name == input_name:
            print(name + ' : ' + str(num + int(input_num)))
         else:
            print(line)


def main():
    entree = sys.argv[1]
    item = sys.argv[2]
    nombre = sys.argv[3]
    choix = str(entree)
    texte = choix.strip("[']")
    maj(texte, item, nombre)

main()
```

Testing it on your example by running

```
python test.py 1.txt apple 23
```

gives the output you requested:

```
apple : 43
orange : 28
```

Edit: perhaps you wish to write the output to a file instead? That can be easily accomplished, I will add the code here:

```
import sys

def maj(input_filename, input_name, input_num, output_filename):
   with open(input_filename, 'r') as f_in:
      with open(output_filename, 'w') as f_out:
         for line in f_in:
            as_list = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), line.split(':')))
            name = as_list[0]
            num = int(as_list[1])
            if name == input_name:
               f_out.write(name + ' : ' + str(num + int(input_num)) + '\n')
            else:
               f_out.write(line)


def main():
    entree = sys.argv[1]
    item = sys.argv[2]
    nombre = sys.argv[3]
    choix = str(entree)
    texte = choix.strip("[']")
    maj(texte, item, nombre, 'my_test_output.txt')

main()
```

This writes the results to `my_test_output.txt`.

Comment: you've used `list()` on a `map()` with a `lambda` which does a `x.strip()` ... just to avoid writing it twice ?! :D nice

Comment: hi thanks for the answer yes i need to write the line into the file. and then if it is missing the item its gonna add it up in an other line. If i replace the my 'my_test_output.txt' with the texte its not writing in the program im telling him to.

Comment: Are you sure you copied it correctly and are giving the correct command-line-arguments? This code is exactly copy pasted from mine.

Comment: ok it is because you remove some behavior i had in my first code. First the .txt file whhere things are gonna be writen from the user is the sys.argv1. i tried to just put it there it didnt work. Also the software is not adding the new line like mine did. i try to modify this

Answer (score 0):

your code:

- opens the file for **append**
- reads all the lines
- (tries to) loops the lines

  - gets the first line
  - decodes it
  - then if it's the input item:

    - increments the counter
    - **writes to the file**
    - **closes the file**
    - **you do a *sys.exit()***
    - **does return, exits the loop, the function, ... everything**
  - other wise does everything as above, except the increment

now read it again and notice your "faults"

the code should me something like

```
'''filename: up.py'''
def get_stored_data(texte):
    stored_data = {}
    with open(texte, "r") as ouvrir:
        for line in ouvrir.readlines():
            if not line: continue
            line = line.split(":")
            stored_data[line[0].strip()] = int(line[1].strip())
    return stored_data

def store_data(texte,data):
    with open(texte, "w") as ouvrir:
        for item, nombre in data.iteritems():
            ouvrir.write("%s : %s" "\n" % (item, nombre))

def maj(input_filename, input_name, input_num, output_filename):
    data = get_stored_data(input_filename)
    data[input_name] = data.get(input_name, 0) + int(input_num)
    store_data(output_filename, data)

def main():
    entree = sys.argv[1]
    item = sys.argv[2]
    nombre = sys.argv[3]
    choix = str(entree)
    texte = choix.strip("[']")
    maj(texte, item, nombre, 'my_test_output.txt')

main()
```

tested it

```
$ cat 1.txt
apple : 20
orange : 28

$ python up.py 1.txt apple 23

$ cat my_test_output.txt
orange : 28
apple : 43
```

for some reason, you are reading on file and write the result to another, but that's not my business

you you want you output file preserve the order in the input file, user `OrderedDict` instead of normal `dict` in `get_stored_data`, the code would be

```
def get_stored_data(texte):
    from collections import OrderedDict
    stored_data = OrderedDict()
    with open(texte, "r") as ouvrir:
        for line in ouvrir.readlines():
            if not line:
                continue
            line = line.split(":")
            stored_data[line[0].strip()] = int(line[1].strip())
    return stored_data
```

Comment: hi yes ive look at this code but i cant figure out why its not working.

Comment: What's the error/failure you get? By the looks of it... It should work. I'll try running it later

Comment: I've noticed the change/difference of the signature of the `maj` method, I've updated the code and tested it